# Unit testing vuex action in typescript, how to pass the this value?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vuex

I'm using Vuex in a typescript setup and want to unit test an action, but having trouble with setting the `this` parameter of the action method.

Action is something like this:

```
export const login: ActionHandler<AuthState, RootState> = ({ commit },
  creds: { email: string, password: string }) => {
};
```

Test is as follows:

```
  describe('actions', () => {
    test('login should call api with credentials', () => {
      (ApiService.post as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue({
        data: { userId: 1234 }
      });
      const commit = jest.fn();
      login({ commit }, { email: 'username@gmail.com', password: 'Pa$$w0rd123' });
    });
  });
```

Problem is the `ActionHandler` is having a signature like:
`login(this: Store<RootState>, injectee: ActionContext<AuthState, RootState>, payload?: any): any`.

And TS is giving me an error:

```
The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Store<RootState>'.ts(2684)
```

I'm unable to figure out how to set an instance of `Store<RootState>` as the `this` of the login action. Am I doing this wrong? I understand this issue would not arise if I use vanilla JS, but would like to keep using TS if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have found two methods of solving a similar problem. Please try.

### 1. Method: Binding `this` (recommended)

You have to bind your `store` to `this` and use the bound action:

```
// Bind
const loginBound = login.bind(store)

// Call
loginBound( /* ... */ );
```

You **might need to define more mocks** for this solution to work. See "Appendix: Full code solution" below.

### 2. Method: Use `Function` cast

By using this approach you will satisfy Typescript but you will kind of **sweep the problem under the rug** (you basically turn off type checks for the action).

```
// Bind
const loginCast = login as Function

// Call
loginCast( /* ... */ );
```

### Appendix: Full code solution

When using the 1st method (binding `this`) you will probably need to provide full action context. The whole solution will look like this:

```
describe('actions', () => {
  test('login should call api with credentials', () => {
    (ApiService.post as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue({
      data: { userId: 1234 }
    });

    // Bind `this`
    const loginBound = login.bind(store)

    // Provide full action context
    const actionContext: ActionContext<AuthState, RootState> = {
      dispatch: jest.fn(),
      commit: jest.fn(),
      state: {}, // here goes your auth state mock
      getters: {},
      rootState: {}, // here goes your root state mock
      rootGetters: {}
    };

    // Call
    loginBound(actionContext, { email: 'username@gmail.com', password: 'Pa$$w0rd123' });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way

```
(login as Function)({ commit: jest.fn() }, { email: 'username.....', password: '..' });
```

In my example I have a complete state:

```
import { Module } from 'vuex';

const cards: Module<any, any> = {
  state: { .... },
  mutations: { .... },
  getters: { ... },
  actions: {
    setCards({ commit }, newCards: string[]) {
      commit('SET_CARD_LIST', newCards);
    }
  }
}
```

And call in jest:

```
(cards.actions!.setCards as Function)(context, ['1001', '1002']);
```

This line removes validations of typescript to ActionContext<any, any>